# How far have people checked if there is a 3×3 magic square of squares?

Tags: square-numbers, magic-square

Basically the titles says it all. I wrote a small Python program to search for 3×3 magic squares with square number entries (using the property of magic squares that Edouard Lucas has discovered --> Every entry is a combination of three numbers a, b and c)
And now I'm wondering if it's even worth running the program for several hours every day or if people have already checked to very big numbers
Unfortunately I couldn't find anything online

Comment: To be sure I understand : You want to build a magic square with the squares $1,4,\cdots , n^4$ ? Must the diagonals also give the same sum ?

Comment: And did you find such a magic square ?

Comment: Progress on magic squares of squares is currently tracked on C. Boyer's site: http://multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquares.htm .  Open sizes: $3 \times 3$ (magic square of any set of squares) and $5 \times 5$ (bimagic squares using distinct integers).

Comment: My question refers to 3x3 magic squares with all required properties (diagonals also have to have the same sum) and all entries need to be square numbers.

Comment: There's a 1000€ prize on finding one, I think

Comment: @Eric Towers Thanks, I have already found this website, but I don't think it shows how many combinations people have checked. My program already checked 63 Billion combinations, I want to know how many have been checked / to what size of the entries people have checked

Comment: @Peter visibly not with **consecutive** squares.

Comment: @EricTowers I am no specialist in magic squares. Does "bimagic square" mean that $1,\cdots, n^2$ form a magic square AND that it remains a magic square if we replace every entry by its square ?

Comment: @Peter : From http://www.multimagie.com/English/Definition.htm : "A magic square is bimagic (or 2-multimagic) if it remains magic after each of its numbers have been squared."

Comment: ... then you would have worked through the list at http://www.multimagie.com/indexengl.htm of current records for searches.

Comment: @Eric Towers Oops, I somehow didn't see that one. Thanks, now I know that I don't need to bother trying to find one (all entries have to be bigger than 10^14, I used 30000 as an upper bound to the search XD)

Comment: @EricTowers - would you mind to make your comment an answer, so that the asker could "accept" it and make the case closed?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms : Your wish is granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Progress on magic squares of squares is currently tracked on [C. Boyer's site](http://multimagie.com/English/SquaresOfSquares.htm). Open sizes: 3×3 (magic square of any set of squares) and 5×5 (bimagic squares using distinct integers).

There is a [list](http://multimagie.com/indexengl.htm) of current records for searches.  It seems that searches up to around $10^{14}$ have already occurred.

Comment: Good aanswer, but maybe we have to hope for updated information. Boyer has provided no updates since 2020.

Comment: @OscarLanzi - at least a sign of life has been sent recently; I'd asked him to update some information, but then retracted after noticing an error in my assumptions. He sent a lively and friendly answer.... seems not a case of "rip" there.